# How to use reduceByKey to add a value into a Set in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

After I map my RDD to

```
((_id_1, section_id_1), (_id_1, section_id_2), (_id_2, section_3), (_id_2, section_4))
```

I want to `reduceByKey` to

```
((_id_1, Set(section_id_1, section_id_2), (_id_2, Set(section_3, section_4)))
```

```
val collectionReduce = collection_filtered.map(item => {
      val extras = item._2.get("extras")
      var section_id = ""
      var extras_id = ""
      if (extras != null) {
        val extras_parse = extras.asInstanceOf[BSONObject]
        section_id = extras_parse.get("guid").toString
        extras_id = extras_parse.get("id").toString
      }
      (extras_id, Set {section_id})
    }).groupByKey().collect()
```

My output is

```
((_id_1, (Set(section_1), Set(section_2))), (_id_2, (Set(section_3), Set(section_4))))
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduceByKey` by simply using `++` to combine the lists.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize((1, Set("A")) :: (2, Set("B")) :: (2, Set("C")) :: Nil)
val reducedRdd = rdd.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
reducedRdd.collect()
// Array((1,Set(A)), (2,Set(B, C)))
```

In your case :

```
collection_filtered.map(item => {
  // ...
  (extras_id, Set(section_id))
}).reduceByKey(_ ++ _).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative with `groupByKey`/`mapValues`

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("_id_1", "section_id_1"), ("_id_1", "section_id_2"), ("_id_2", "section_3"), ("_id_2", "section_4")))

rdd.groupByKey().mapValues( v => v.toSet).foreach(println)
```

Here is another alternative using `combineByKey` (recommended over `groupByKey`) :

```
rdd.combineByKey(
        (value: String) => Set(value),
        (x: Set[String], value: String) => x + value ,
        (x: Set[String], y:     Set[String]) => (x ++ y)
    ).foreach(println)
```

Comment: What's different between using reduceByKey above and your way? Which one is better? Thanks.

Comment: The `groupByKey` is simpler, here, as you do not aggregate ("*reduce*") any information between two key-value pairs having the same keys : you just concatenate the values together. The implementation with reduce will do the same work, just in a slightly harder to read version.

Comment: You should prefer `reduceByKey` over `groupByKey` in general, look at this [Spark gitbook](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) for an explanation.

Comment: @Peter Neyens : Thanks for link